PostgreSQL authentication fails with Apache Arrow Flight SQL Driver
Original post
I want to try out the Apache Arrow Flight SQL Driver for a large OLAP query on a PostgreSQL database. When I run the following example:
import adbc_driver_flightsql.dbapi
import adbc_driver_manager

conn = adbc_driver_flightsql.dbapi.connect('flightsql://username:password@172.20.30.40:5432/database')

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT 1")
    assert cur.fetchone() == (1,)
conn.close()

I keep getting this error:

adbc_driver_manager.OperationalError: IO: [FlightSQL] connection
error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: EOF"
(Unavailable; Prepare)

However, I can reach the DB using the normal adbc PostgreSQL Driver without issues:
conn = adbc_driver_postgresql.dbapi.connect('postgresql://username:password@172.20.30.40:5432/database')

I followed these instructions to install Flight SQL (I run Debian 12) and then added shared_preload_libraries = 'arrow_flight_sql' in postgresql.conf per this, plus restart. Any idea what I'm missing?
Update
Using @Zeroshade's connection request, I get a connection refused answer:

[FlightSQL] connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 172.20.30.40:15432: connect: connection refused" (Unavailable; AuthenticateBasicToken)

Trying netcat (nc -vz 172.20.30.40 15432) on that port also yielded:

nc: connect to 172.20.30.40 port 15432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

So I checked netstat (netstat -an | grep "LISTEN ") to see if the server listens on that port and lo and behold: for some reason it's only listening on IPv6 and localhost...

tcp6    0    0    127.0.0.1:15432    :::*    LISTEN

Which brings me to my new question: Does anybody know in what config file I can adjust what IP the arrow_flight_sql module listens on?

You asked this on dba.se 12 hours ago. Cross-posting is frowned on - at least have the decency to put forward/back links in the relevant posts to help eliminate duplication of effort or delete your question on dba.se!

I had deleted the other one and then posted this one, given that the Apache Arrow docs recommend posting here. So what's your problem...?

Oops - my bad - didn't refresh the page! Showing as deleted now, thanks!

Looking at the link you provided, most likely the issue is the port.
In your post you said that you used postgresql://username:password@172.20.30.40:5432/database as the URI to connect, note the port being 5432. In the link to the config documentation, the default port is 15432 and uses a different scheme than flightsql.
Can you try using grpc://172.20.30.40:15432 as your URI and setting the username and password using options?
It also looks like you need to set an extra header option to set the database.
Like so:
import adbc_driver_flightsql.dbapi
import adbc_driver_manager

conn = adbc_driver_flightsql.dbapi.connect('grpc://172.20.30.40:15432',
           db_kwargs={
              adbc_driver_manager.DatabaseOptions.USERNAME.value: "username",
              adbc_driver_manager.DatabaseOptions.PASSWORD.value: "password",
           },
           conn_kwargs={
              "adbc.flight.sql.rpc.call_header.x-flight-sql-database": "database",
           })

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT 1")
    assert cur.fetchone() == (1,)
conn.close()


Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I get a "connection refused" message on this port. I will update the original post with more details shortly.

I believe you should be able to specify the uri via the "arrow_flight_sql.uri" setting in postgresql.conf. By default it is grpc://127.0.0.1:15432, but maybe you could set it to grpc://172.20.30.40:15432 and that would work?

Thanks. Updating that in postgresql.conf did the trick. I can now connect to the database with the Flight SQL driver. But as soon as I run even the simplest query (Limit 100 on a table), the whole database locks up to the point where I can't even restart it anymore using systemctl, but need to force off the server physically. Very frustrating this... Not sure if others have been more successful, but this Flight SQL driver seems to be too experimental at the moment, at least for my capabilities...
